# How to timeout inputbox in whiptail?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, timeout, whiptail

I would like to ask user for some data, and if inactive, then exit. But `whiptail` has no such option as `--timeout`.  I have tried something like

```
 timeout 5 whiptail --inputbox "enter your name" 10 20
```

But will leave mess in the terminal windows. So is there some way to timeout the whiptail in shell?

Comment: This might help: `timeout 5 whiptail --inputbox "enter your name" 10 20; reset; clear`

Answer (score 1):

or
dialog  --timeout 5 --inputbox  "enter your name" 10 2 :